# find pdf text in IE9 browser using selenium

Tags: javascript, ruby, pdf, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In our application while clicking the link it will open the new window with secure pdf file. We want to validate that using selenium ruby. but We unable to validate this in IE9 [because there is no html/dom element]

We can perform this validation using firefox and chrome browser because there  html/DOM element present for that pdf page.

Is another way to validate pdf text from browser URL?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is possible.  Chrome and Firefox, do, indeed render more that is actually there, usually for more powerful embedding, etc.

I can offer a solution however,

Instead of navigating to the PDF, you can validate the `href` of the link.

*here is some pseudo-code from Java on how to accomplish the task...*

```
String href = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href$='.pdf']")).getAttribute("href");
assertTrue(href.contains("FileName.pdf"));
```

From these two statements, we'll know two things:

1. The link is indeed taking you to a PDF file.
2. The PDF file, is called `FileName`

If the test fails in any way, that means that the link doesn't exist, or points to the **wrong** pdf.

Comment: Thanks @sircapsalot . our link is <a title="click you link" onclick="your
FunOnClick();return false;" href="#">, And we need to validate pdf context not pdf file name text.